# How to make PHP and NodeJS communicate via socket?

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm adding a realtime notification to an existing PHP application with (Node Js + Socket.io).
I create the client's part, now I want to notify NodeJs server via socket.
I found other solutions then sockets:

```
Sharing data via redis (hard to implement).
DNode Library.
```

I simplest way is HTTP requests using native functions (Node Server) and curl for (PHP).
Please is there any example to start with?

Comment: I found that using SOCKET is the simplest way.